# Do "I guess" and "I would say" have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

I often read sentences where the idea is "I would say" but it starts with "I guess". For example:

> - **I would say** he is not coming.
> - **I guess** he is not coming.

Do both have the same meaning?

Comment: Though "I guess" is more familiar to me (US Midwest), "I would say" seems to imply the same thing, I'm speculating that he is not coming.  If I knew for sure, I would say "He is not coming".

Comment: I guess they do. :^) By the way, I noticed you haven't joined the newly-started site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) yet. I would say that questions like this one might fare better there.

Comment: @J.R.: I guess some would say you got your two usages the wrong way round, there. But I think it's Not Constructive to analyse exactly why!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have only very approximately the same meaning, in that both imply some degree of uncertainty and leave room for others or for facts-on-the-ground to contradict what follows.

- ***I would say*** characterizes what follows as a personal opinion or judgment: *From what I know of him I would say he is coming.*
- ***I guess*** characterizes what follows as a conjecture or inference: *Well, if he were coming he'd be here by now, so I guess he's not coming.*

But there's obviously room for some overlap: an opinion may be based on inference, and a conjecture may be based on opinion.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: @Adam_G Nothing beyond 67 years of listening and reading.